# issue while changing Navigation Root View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

I am making an app. In which First User have to sign In then He allowed to use the app.

After successful login I want the user to directly switch to my HomeViewController.

Here is my code tho change navigation root view but it is not working

```
   TermsConditionsController *firstViewController = [[TermsConditionsController alloc]init];
   FirstPage *secondViewController =  [[FirstPage alloc]init];

   firstViewController.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject: secondViewController];


FirstPage *nextScr = (FirstPage *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstPage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScr animated:YES];
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using storyboards or managing navigation programatically? Because "firstViewController" has no navigationController assigned to it according to your code.

Comment: did you solve your problem? Looking for a clue

Comment: Found the answer to our question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414786/instead-of-push-segue-how-to-replace-view-controller-or-remove-from-navigation#21415225 by christophercotton

Answer (score 0):

Connect your LoginViewController with HomeViewController by using segue.

give the identifier for the segue for ex name:successLogin.

and use this method:

```
[self performSegueIdentifier:@"successLogin" sender:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

**Note: Change controller name as per your controllers**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UINavigationController *navController;

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginUserDetails"]) {
    // Already logged in
    ProfileViewController *profileVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileVC"];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileVC];
}else{
    // Not Login Yet
    LoginViewController *loginVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
}

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
}
// Write this code when user login successfully
if (/*Login Successfully*/) {
    // Then add loginUserDetails in userdefaults.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"loginUserDetails"];// Instead of nil pass here your object
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: when user successfully login..how can i move him to home Controller

Comment: create a segue between home and login view controller and just push controller when login successful

Comment: I have created  a chat room ...lets dicuss over there