# Issue with using RGB colors in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibutton, xcode6, uicolor

I want to use `RGB` color to set set background color of `UIButton`.

I have lots of `UIButtons` so I decided to make a custom class.But when I try to use `colorWithRed` I am getting  error.

> First Code:

```
[self.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:60/255.0f green:146/255.0f blue:180/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

**Error**

[image]

> Second Code

```
  self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60/255.0f green:146/255.0f blue:180/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Read the error message!  A layer's background color is a CGColor, not a UIColor.

Comment: @matt How can i Use RGB to CGColor

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIColor/CGColor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use this code

```
self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60/255.0f green:146/255.0f blue:180/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
```

You need to convert UIColor to CGColor which can be done by above code.

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: It is working..thanx malav...could be please assist me to solve one of my problem

Comment: If you another issue please create another question I will help you there for sure

Comment: yes i will..but not here may make a chat room or some where else like gmail.or skype ?

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001518/issue-while-changing-navigation-root-view-controller?noredirect=1#comment48122826_30001518

Comment: reputation le k chale gaye :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76853/discussion-between-rahulmishra-and-malav-soni).

Answer (score 1):

layer backgroundcolor is of cgcolorref type, so cant use uicolor. we need to use cgcolor or convert uicolor to cgcolor and use it.

example:

```
[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

or

```
[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023404/issue-with-using-rgb-colors-in-ios/30026414#