# How to Dismiss Model View Controller before push?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

Currently my scenario like this ,

```
View Controller(VC1)  -->  Push Segue --> View Controller(VC2)
          |                                   ^ 
          | Model Segue                       |
          |                                   | Push Segue
          |-----> View Controller(VC3)  ------|
```

Now in `VC3`  when i push in to `VC2` i want to dismiss `VC3` view Controller and 
on after `VC2` back button it should be `VC1's` back view controller i want to pop VC3

What i want is i want to remove VC3 when i push the VC2 from VC3 when we back then it VC1 should appear

[Check Example](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69811463087160928732)

I have done like this can anyone help me out

**View Controller (VC3)** :

```
- (void)callWebservice {

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showVC2" sender:self];
   }];

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think we have another option.

Comment: @CongTran i want to pop VC3 then after i want to push to VC2

Comment: I don't get the question .. above code will do what what you want .. don't get it

Comment: @Daij-Djan what i want is i want to remove VC3 when i push the VC2 from VC3 when we back then it VC1 should appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can implement in that way:

- when you at screen 3 you want push screen 2. You will dismiss screen 3 and call a delegate back screen 1.
- And from screen1 you will push view to screen2.

You can see my demo for my idea: [Demo Pushview Swift](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoPushView)

[DemoPushViewObj](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoPushViewObj)

Comment: can u do in objective C?

Comment: @BlackCop  It's ok. Wait me I will give you demo in Objetive-c.

Comment: Yes i can see that but my scenario different from you  check demo http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69811463087160928732

Comment: @BlackCop ah I see. You want push. I have modified code in this case. Check it.

Comment: it's working but a one issue there when we r going to push from VC3 to vc2 then a little bit timt VC1 is showing how to hide that problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97507/discussion-between-black-cop-and-vien-vu).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415225/1320305 if you are using segue, to do this manually try following:

you can try this

```
 // locally store the navigation controller since
 // self.navigationController will be nil once we are popped
 UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

 // retain ourselves so that the controller will still exist once it's popped off
 [[self retain] autorelease];

 // Pop this controller and replace with another
 [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];//not to see pop

 [navController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
//to see push or u can change it to not to see.
```

OR try this

```
UIViewController *newVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // Replace the current view controller 
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
[viewControllers removeLastObject]; 
[viewControllers addObject:newVC]; 
[[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: i think this will not work because see this thing that i did

Comment: i didn't get you, where i have to do this ?

Comment: i think in your callWebservice method call. remove current code and place any one of the option.

Comment: are you getting any error or something can you share some more code excerpt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97492/discussion-between-a4arpan-and-black-cop).