# Logout from TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

What is the best way to log out from a TabBar. I have an app which in one of its tabs has a log out option in a row. When I tab this row I want to go to my log in screen. The app launch the log in screen if you are not log in or the main screen (is a tab bar controller) if you are already log gin. I manage this in the appDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let notFisrtRun = defaults.boolForKey("notFirstRun")

    // Chooses between login view and my list view if the user is already authenticated when the app is launched
    if AuthToken.sharedInstance.isAuthenticated() && notFisrtRun {
        let tabBarViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController") as? UITabBarController

        self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarViewController
    } else {
        let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController

        self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

- If I try a show segue to my log in screen, it appear with the navigation bar and tab bar.
- If I try an unwind segue, it work in the case you are not already log in and the app start with log in screen.But in the cases the app start with the tab bar controller because you are already log in, it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: what did you do for the final answer? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty normal for apps to show login screens modally. Upon logout, Present `loginViewController` **modally**. If the user logs back in, dismiss the `loginViewController`.

You could also create a custom segue that replaces the `rootViewController`, [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414786/instead-of-push-segue-how-to-replace-view-controller-or-remove-from-navigation) can get you started on that.