# Programmatically connect the other view controller with buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 4 viewcontroller like, home , sign in, sign up, Forgot password Viewcontroller's. And I set the storyboard identity for all view controller.In my each screen I have 1 or 2 button and I need to connect the other view controller programmatically with **replace seague** Here is my full details about screen , buttonname( action ), destination VC Screens

```
 Home screen =  sign in button  = signinvc ( storyboard identity Vc's)
                    sign Up button  = SignUpvc( storyboard identity Vc's)

    SignIn VC =  NotRegisterBtn          = SignUpvc( storyboard identity Vc's)
                    forgot password Button  =  forgotvc( storyboard identity Vc's)


    SignUp VC = AlreadyReg_Button = Sign In VC( storyboard identity Vc's)

    Forgot VC = CancelBtn  = SignIn vc( storyboard identity Vc's)
```

How to do that in full programmatically?

Updated:

```
-(void) methodone {

}


-(void) methodtwo {
}
```

Now how can i show the presentedviewmodal vc for this two button method action..First method should go to `signVc`, second method should go to `signInVC`

Answer (score 0):

You can add action to buttons and then create custom segues for replacement.

[You can check correct answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414786/instead-of-push-segue-how-to-replace-view-controller-or-remove-from-navigation)

Comment: Actually 1. HomeVC. i programatically create two button signIn Button, SignUp button. And i have two action for that. when i add presentedmodalVc seguage its getting null