# undoing a modal and show segue at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, segue, unwind-segue

I have a `UITableView` (let's call it HomeVC) and when you press the cells it takes you to a details page via a show segue. On that details (DetailsVC) page, there is an edit button which modally brings up an edit view (EditVC) with a delete option. When the delete option is pressed, I want to go back to the HomeVC, "unwinding" (if that's the correct term) the EditVC and DetailsVC.

Right now my delete button (in EditVC) brings up an `ActionSheet` to confirm deletion with the destroy(delete) button doing:

```
let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm Delete", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
    //handle deletion stuff...

    // send user back to HomeVC
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    //also tried self.parentViewController?.dismiss...                   
}
```

The `dismissViewController` works to get rid of the modal segue from DetailsVC to EditVC, bringing me back to DetailsVC, but since this item is now deleted I don't want to see its details, I want to go all the way back to HomeVC. How could I accomplish this? Can I do it all from EditVC in the function above?

EDIT: If you're coming here from search/google, this is what I used to finally get it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879562/2868510

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: that seems to do nothing. I tried calling just this, calling it after `dismissViewControllerAnimated()`, and calling it in `completion`. The only thing that would happen is the `dismissViewControllerAnimated()`