# How to push two view controllers modally without seeing the first one

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, presentviewcontroller

I want to present two view controllers in a row, without seeing the first one.
I want to be able to return from the second one to the first.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857222/how-to-push-two-view-controllers-but-animate-transition-only-for-the-second-one), but the responses focus on using the navigation controller, while I want to present the second view controller modally.

The use case is: My initial VC check if the user is logged in, and presents the login VC if not.
If yes, it displays the main VC.
On logout, I should be able to unwind to the login VC.

Answer (score 1):

A suitable solution would be **presenting the second view controller first** and only presenting the first one after the second one fully appeared.

**InitialViewController**

```
let secondVc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! SecondViewController
secondVc.initialVc = self
present(secondVc, animated: true)
```

**SecondViewController**

```
fileprivate var firstViewDidAppearTime = true
var initialVc: InitialViewController!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if firstViewDidAppearTime {
        firstViewDidAppearTime = false

        let firstVc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First")
        initialVc.present(firstVc, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't have a navigation controller !

Comment: I got "warning: attempt to present <firstViewContainer>" on <baseViewContainer> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I meant firstViewController and baseViewController